# How to set order of custom ProtocolMapper in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have many custom ProtocolMapper in keycloak and they work fine.

But order of work is not clear for me. I was thinking that order equals order of string in org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper but it is not true.

My registration file

```
com.example.sso.mapper.FirstMapper // work second
com.example.sso.mapper.SecondMapper // work first
com.example.sso.mapper.ThirdMapper // work third
```

How can i controll order of they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you cannot control the order of mappers. If one mapper depends on information that another mapper sets, maybe you should consider turning them into a single mapper. The `setClaim` function can add multiple claims to a token at the same time. That way you can be certain that all your required claims are set.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the order of your custom mappers. Keycloak documentation [mentions this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#priority-order).

Each mapper has priority index assigned to it, the lowest the index the earlier it gets called.

To change priority index for your custom mapper, you need to override [ProtocolMapper#getPriority](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.4/javadocs/org/keycloak/protocol/ProtocolMapper.html#getPriority()) method.

```
public class MyProtocolMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper {
    
    @Override
    public int getPriority() {
        return 10;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

In your particular case just make sure that

```
FirstMapper.getPriority() < SecondMapper.getPriority() < ThirdMapper.getPriority()
```

This will run these particular mappers in the sequence you expect. I hope this helps.